# Where are cpu tags taken into account

Tags: bazel

https://bazel.googlesource.com/bazel/+show/master/CHANGELOG.md mentions, that there are `cpu` tags. Of course now the question to me is where else these tags are being taken into account.

Comment: That was added by [da21ba7](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/da21ba7a48ea4f3a1b67dbecfc3d30c93b42beac); I'm summoning [@philwo](https://github.com/philwo) to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the commit message here as I think it answers the question perfectly:

TLDR:  You can increase the CPU reservation for tests by adding a "cpu:" (e.g. "cpu:4" for four cores) tag to their rule in a BUILD file. This can be used if tests would otherwise overwhelm your system if there's too much parallelism.

This lets users specify that their test needs a minimum of  CPU cores
to run and not be flaky. Example for a reservation of 4 CPUs:

```
sh_test(
  name = "test",
  size = "large",
  srcs = ["test.sh"],
  tags = ["cpu:4"],
)
```

This could also be used by remote execution strategies to tune their
resource adjustment.

---

As of 2017-06-21 the following alternating options are possible:

**genrule**: Setting `tags` same as in `sh_test`.
Example:

```
genrule(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = [],
    outs = ["foo.h"],
    cmd = "./$(location create_foo.pl) > \"$@\"",
    tools = ["create_foo.pl"],
    tags = ["cpu:4"],
)
```

**Skylark rules**: *This can work as long as you do NOT use Workers. [See](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3232).*
For Skylark rules `cpu` can be set manually for any created action individually. This is accomplished by setting `execution_requirements`.
Example:

```
ctx.action(
    execution_requirements = {
        "cpu:4": "", # This is no mistake - you really encode the value in the dict key and an empty string in dict value
    },
)
```

Comment: Ok. I was hoping that one could add this to any action by now. E.g. I have an action that I know processes using three threads. Thus I could really use this beyond mere tests/rules.

Comment: So it looks these tags should also work with genrules and skylark custom rules too. If they don't, it's a bug worth reporting :)

Comment: So is the semantic then, that the cpu reservation gets added to all actions of that rule?

Comment: For skylark rules, you have to set the tag for every action individually, genrules and tests have only 1 action, and the tag is set there automatically.

Comment: How does one set on action? Looking at https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/ctx.html#action it seems like there is no `tags` to be set. Is this just not documented?

Comment: It's the execution_requirements dictionary, and key is "cpu:4", value is empty. I'm with you on the wtf there :)